# Setting the ImageButton as invisible and retaining it when home/back Button of the phone is pressed or orientation changes is not working?

Tags: android, visibility, imagebutton, onclicklistener

In my application I have a ImageButton inside an EditText. When the ImageButton is clicked In my application I have a ImageButton inside an EditText. When the ImageButton is clicked I make it invisible using VIEW.GONE and enter some text in the EditText. I want to retain the ImageButton as invisible when the home button,back button of the phone is pressed and also when the orientation is changed. Can someone please help me, how this can be done?

Here is part of the code:

In Oncreate method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_flip_card);
    edt_aroundMsg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_aroundMsg);
    if(savedInstanceState!=null){
        onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
      }
```

ImageButton onClickListener:

```
btn_msg_tap = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_msg_tap);
    btn_msg_tap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            btn_msg_tap.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            edt_aroundMsg.setPadding(20, 10, 0, 0);
            edt_aroundMsg.setEnabled(true);
            // edt_aroundMsg.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            edt_aroundMsg.requestFocus();
            InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            im.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);

        }
    });
```

In onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState method:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {       
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("message", edt_aroundMsg.getText().toString());
    outState.putInt("font_size", font_size);
    outState.putBoolean("edt_msg_enabled", edt_aroundMsg.isEnabled());
    //outState.putByte("font_style", tf);
}
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    edt_enabled = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("edt_msg_enabled");
    /*if (edt_enabled == true){
        btn_msg_tap.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    else{
        btn_msg_tap.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }*/
    str_edtMsg = savedInstanceState.getString("message");
    font_size = savedInstanceState.getInt("font_size");
    edt_aroundMsg.setText(str_edtMsg);
    edt_aroundMsg.setTextSize(font_size);

}
```

I may be missing something,due to my inexperience I am having difficulty in solving this problem. Please help me asap. Thanks.

Comment: There is no issue about visibility of ImageButton as you know how to change its visibility. But its the issue about how to detect home/back button is pressed.There are so many questions regarding how to detect home/back button pressed on SO. Please well search before asking.

Comment: @Geet Thanks, for the suggestion. I have searched a lot but wasn't able to solve the problem.That is why I have posted hoping to get an answer that can solve my problem. I have updated the code above which most people have given as solutions to such kind of issues, but it doesn't work or I may be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can detect when home button is pressed:
put below code on Every Activity

```
    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
        if (!taskInfo.isEmpty()) {
            ComponentName topActivity = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity; 
            if (!topActivity.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {

                Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "You Left your App", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

// retain the ImageButton as invisible .
            }
        }
    }
```

Detect back button press:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();

            Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Back pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
// retain the ImageButton as invisible .

    }
```

Detect Orientation changes:

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  }
//You also have to edit the appropriate element in your manifest file to include the //android:configChanges Just see the code below:

<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Comment: is this line mandatory to add? xmppclient.disconnect(getBaseContext()); I read about it and said that xmppclient is a software that enables you to connect to an XMPP for instant messaging with other people over the Internet. Its not relevant for my application. I did not write this line and it doesn't work. The ImageButton becomes visible again.

Comment: But all these methods you have shared are not working. I still see the ImageButton as it is whenever back/home button is pressed and when orientation changes. Would it help if I post my code for you to see what's going on?

Comment: do you get any toast when home/back button pressed or orientation change? if you get the toast then my answer is not wrong so u cant say it like that this methods are not working. May be its visibility issue which u are not getting at that time. so verify its visibility.